# ProgressBar is not functioning in android activity

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-progressbar, buttonclick

I am using progressbar in simple login application.But the progress bar is not showing .Sometimes when i change the position of the progressbar is shows before the calling progressbar.show();
here is My XML code

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    >
</ProgressBar>
```

In onCreate() method:

```
 progressBar= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

In button oncliklistener

```
 btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            uid=usrusr.getText().toString().trim();
            upass=pswd.getText().toString().trim();

            try {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                checkLogin(uid,upass);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

I have tried many other solutions from stackoverflow but none of them worked
Thanks:/

Comment: call progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE) only on success of checklogin

Comment: try to hide your **progressBar** in **checkLogin** method

Comment: hi in try block you have used  progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); and   progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); are parallel so progressbar is always gone

Comment: I have removed the code from try catch, and placed outside.. But still not working 

Comment: paste your checklogin method

Comment: Try removing `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` for instance. This will help you confirm that either Progressbar is displaying or not.

Comment: After removing View. Invisible Progressbar shows before its called.. And for that when I use invisible or gone it doesn't display

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.

```
    private ProgressDialog progDailog;
    private Button btn_login;
    private EditText uid, upass;
    private String uid1, upass1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progDailog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progDailog.setTitle("Login");
        progDailog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progDailog.setCancelable(false);

        btn_login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        uid = findViewById(R.id.uid);
        upass = findViewById(R.id.upass);

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                uid1 = uid.getText().toString().trim();
                upass1 = upass.getText().toString().trim();

                progDailog.show();


                checkLogin(uid1, upass1);

                Runnable progressRunnable = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progDailog.dismiss();
                    }
                };

                Handler pdCanceller = new Handler();
                pdCanceller.postDelayed(progressRunnable, 3000);

            }
        });
    }
```

Here 3000 is milliseconds which means 3 seconds, you can change it according to your requirement.

Your XML will be like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/uid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="uid" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/upass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="upass" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="btn_login" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please try this and let me know if you require any other changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try added code to show the `progressBar` before calling the api and dismiss the `progressBar` on `response` of the request.

Ex.

```
void checkLogin(String name, String psd){
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //start the api call
}

void onApiCallresponse(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //code for what you want to do after login
         }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that your "data processing" code is running on the UI thread, blocking any visible changes. I would suggest trying putting

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

If your progressBar still not showing and nothing helps

Answer (score 0):

You can show your progress for 3 second like this :

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, 3000) ;

    checkLogin(uid,upass);
```

But it is better to show your progress when you start to check login and invoke api and hide it when you receive a result.

Comment: The point of ProgressBar is to show that a  call is running so it should be shown and hidden depending on the result of the call. And if the call is finished earlier why wait for 3 sec? 
Your last statement is true

Comment: The first statement  is about an approximative prediction of the time spending on executing the process. You can do it when you don't know and you don't have the result callbacks. 
The second statement is when you have the callbacks that indicate that you receive a resullt.